# Is there a similar function draw-on-you-screen (Gnome extension) in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

Hope you are doing fine? I'm currently using Ubuntu Unity desktop, but during my trial period with Gnome-shell, I found the extension draw-on-you-screen very useful? Is there an alternative for Unity? Thanks in advance

Draw on your screen